# multiple comparisons in a single sql query

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-like

I need to get the rows of address by comparing two columns in diffrent view

one is a database of addresses

```
    CREATE TABLE IDData (
    id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    cgi     STRING,
    cellid  STRING,
    address STRING,
);
```

there is another table,

```
CREATE TABLE cdata (
    id       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   fcellid  TEXT,
);

IDData
id  cgi            cellid      address
1   123456789879   9879        512- baker street london
2   {blank}        9462        23 panama beach
3   456789879324   {blank}     Chandni chowk delhi

cdata
id    fcellid
1     123456789879
2     9462
3     9324
```

result should be

```
fcellid        address
123456789879   512- baker street london
9462           23 panama beach
9324           Chandni chowk delhi
```

now what i tried to is

```
SELECT fcellid,iii.address FROM cdata as dd left JOIN IDData as iii ON (iii.cgi like '%' || dd.fcellid or dd.fcellid like '%' || iii.cgi) or (iii.cellid like '%' || dd.fcellid or dd.fcellid like '%' || iii.cellid );
```

but not workin as expecting giving too much results as it is returning results from every condition, i want to get only the results for the number of fcellid in cdata.

Comment: I don't understand how `9324` is related to `512- baker street london`.

Comment: Can you explain how the tables should be compared, it's difficult to tell from the example data here?

Comment: cgi is more specific cellid, so every cgi ends with cellid

Comment: so the fcellid should be compare to either cellid or cgi, there are four cases here, 1st is when fcellid is equilant to cellid then it can be matched directly,2nd when fcellid is eqquilant to cgi then it can be matched directly,but when cgi is not available and fcellid is in big format cellid should be matched to fcellid, and if cellid is not available and fcellid is in small format then fcellid should be compared to cgi

Answer (score 1):

I think this logic does what you want:

```
SELECT fcellid, i.address
FROM cdata dd left join
     IDData i
     ON dd.fcellid like ('%' || i.cgi) or
        dd.fcellid like ('%' || i.cellid) ;
```

Or, more simply:

```
SELECT fcellid, i.address
FROM cdata dd left join
     IDData i
     ON dd.fcellid ~ concat('(', i.cgi, '|', i.cellid, ')$')
```

However, this doesn't quite return your desired result set, because the match for row 3 is `'Chandni chowk delhi'`, rather than one of the other values.

Comment: yes you are right i corrected it, but your query returns more results because of the one condition which evaluated to false

Comment: `SELECT dd.fcellid, i.address
FROM dd left join
     r166 i
     ON dd.fcellid == i.cellid
     OR i.cgi like '%'||dd.fcellid
     OR dd.fcellid like '%'||i.cgi
     OR dd.fcellid == i.cgi;`
this is the complete logic but it returns unknown data set,

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN type of join is going to return you in other scenarios more records that are you expecting if I understand well your issue. I believe is better use INNER JOIN or just JOIN which is the same thing.

```sql
SELECT fcellid, address 
FROM
cdata (NOLOCK)
JOIN IDData (NOLOCK) 
ON 
cgi LIKE CONCAT('%',fcellid)
OR 
cellid LIKE CONCAT ('%', fcellid)
```

Also is always a good practice use (NOLOCK) in your SELECT statements.

Comment: Offtopic, but is usually bad practice to use `(nolock)` in `select` statements, unless you can be sure that data does never change while querying.